# flutter depends on share >=0.2.1 <2.0.0-nullsafety.2 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed

Tags: flutter

The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.5.

Because depends on share >=0.2.1 <2.0.0-nullsafety.2 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=1.8.0 <2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev.28.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
Process finished with exit code 1

pubspec.yaml

```
description: A new Flutter application.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  #BASE
  nb_utils: ^4.4.10
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0

  #UI
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  flutter_speed_dial: ^5.0.0+1

  #STATE MANAGEMENT
  mobx: ^2.0.5
  flutter_mobx: ^2.0.2

  #STORAGE & PERMISSION
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0
  flutter_downloader: ^1.7.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  provider: ^6.0.1

  #CONNECTIVITY
  http: ^0.13.4
  share: ^0.4.0

  url_launcher: ^6.0.17
  store_redirect: ^2.0.0

  #Firebase
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.6.0+5
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.4
  firebase_core: ^1.10.6

  # PUSH NOTIFICATION
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.2.7

  # ADS
  google_mobile_ads: ^1.0.1

  # WEB TOOLS
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.1.7
  mobx_codegen: ^2.0.4
  #flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - lang/
```

it gives an error so i can't get build

Answer (score 0):

As per the error you are getting, the sdk version you have does not have null-safety feature enabled.

Try `flutter upgrade` if you are running below flutter 3 and update the SDK

from

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

to

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0' or higher
```